# javascript background image position looping

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, settimeout

This is my code:

```
function time(){
     function image1(){
           document.getElementById("letOrSellBannerHousePrice").style.backgroundPosition = "-754px 0px";
     }
     function time1(){
        setTimeout("image1()", 5000);
     }
     function image2(){
        document.getElementById("letOrSellBannerHousePrice").style.backgroundPosition = "-1508px 0px";
     }
     function time2(){
        setTimeout("image2()", 11000);
     }

     function backToOriginal(){
         document.getElementById("letOrSellBannerHousePrice").style.backgroundPosition = "0px 0px";
     }
     function time3(){
        setTimeout("backToOriginal()", 17000);
     }
     function init(){
        time1();
        time2();
        time3();
     }
    }
    function runThis(){
        time();
    }
    window.onload = runThis;
```

I want the background image to be scrolling but when I run the program the script don't run. I can't find my mistake.

this is what i put on my css code `background:url("image source");`

can this be done.
please help im new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `time` function there are only defenitions of functions, but there is no calling. Try to add

```
init();
```

At the bottom of the `time` function.

Also replace

```
setTimeout("image1()", 5000);
```

by

```
setTimeout(image1, 5000);
```

and so on.